# sublime connection to localhost:57734 timed out

Tags: python, server, anaconda, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

[image]

[image]

I get this popup error whenever I open my sublimetext3.

Answer (score 0):

In Anaconda package find file `local_worker.py`, then find `check` method. Set value of the variable `interval` to 5. If you still get this message, increase value.